# How to do I/O on a pointer to a base class?

Tags: c++, io

For example, I have a base class `A` and its derived classes `B`, `C`, and so on. I have data with a pointer pointing to `A`. It might be `new B`, `new C`, and so on. Any easy way to write and read the pointer to/from a stream? My question is on how to get to know the concrete type. An example to show what I mean.

```
struct A            { int i; };
struct B : public A { char c; };
struct C : public A { float f; }

struct Data
{
    unique_ptr<A> mA;
};

Data data;
```

User works on `data` and then write out to a file and read in from the file.

Comment: The point of encapsulation is that you generally don't need to know. If you want some specialized behavior, just declare a virtual function in A and override as needed in the derived classes. If that's not helpful, then I recommend you define "write and read the pointer to/from a stream".

Comment: I agree with Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you don't, you use virtual functions.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
    virtual void describe() {
        std::cout << "A:" << i << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B : public A {
    char c;
    virtual void describe() override {
        // Assume a 'B' wants to also output the A stuff.
        std::cout << "B:" << c << ":";
        A::describe();
    }
};
struct C : public B {
    float f;
    virtual void describe() override {
        // Assume a 'C' wants to also output the B stuff and A stuff.
        std::cout << "C:" << f << ":";
        B::describe();
    }
};

#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<A*> bar;
    A a;
    a.i = 10;
    B b;
    b.i = 22;
    b.c = 'b';
    C c;
    c.i = 5;
    c.c = 'X';
    c.f = 123.456;
    bar.push_back(&a);
    bar.push_back(&b);
    bar.push_back(&c);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bar.size(); ++i) {
        bar[i]->describe();
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/12BEce

Comment: Exactly the same way? Just add a function argument and make sure it is consistent between functions. `virtual void read(istream& from);` and `virtual void read(istream& from) override` in derived classes.

Comment: You're going to have to have constructed the object before you can start reading into, so the vtable is in-place. If you are asking "how can I have a pointer to the correct object in advance of starting to read", that merits its own question (and has probably already been asked). But at some point you'll have to have enough information to tell, what condition you are in. You could either first write a type indicator so that you can construct the correct type before starting read and have a switch statement or hash that maps type -> constructor (using a factory).